# MongoDB AddToSet how to prevent duplicate by specific fields?

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of objects in an entity in a DB record.
I want to push new object to that array, but I don't want to push the same object multiple times. I know I can use `$addToSet`, but the problem occurs that in each object I add timestamp, so this method doesn't distinguish that the object already in the array, it fully compare the objects and if the timestamp has changed it will add it twice so I will have:

```
[
  { a: 1, timestamp: X },
  { a: 1, timestamp: X+Y }
]
```

As you can see I already have `a`, but since timestamps has changed, for `$addToSet` it is okay to add this object once again.

How can I check agains specific fields, so I will check only against `a` property - ignoring the timestamp?

Comment: You can do all of that in the application and use $push when you decide to insert `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using a bulkWrite operation to issue 2 commands in one go. first one to remove the matching array document. and then to push a new one in to the array. so there will be no duplicates in the array.

say you have the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("606dc0a6a142af062c5ed9bc"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "a" : 1,
            "timestamp" : 12345
        },
        {
            "a" : 2,
            "timestamp" : 54321
        }
    ]
}
```

you can issue the following bulk write command to achieve your goal:

```
db.Collection.bulkWrite(
[
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: {
                _id: ObjectId("606dc0a6a142af062c5ed9bc")
            },
            update: {
                "$pull": {
                    array: { a: 2 }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: {
                _id: ObjectId("606dc0a6a142af062c5ed9bc")
            },
            update: {
                "$push": {
                    array: {
                        a: 2,
                        timestamp: 99999
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

the above will replace the array object if it exists with the supplied one. if you need to only insert an object if it doesn't exist in the array and if it does exist, do nothing, then you can do this:

```
db.Collection.updateOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("606dc0a6a142af062c5ed9bc"),
        "array.a": { $ne: 3 }
    },
    {
        $push: {
            array: {
                a: 3,
                timestamp: 55555
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: That is nice, but it requires two commands - I made it using one: first look up if the entity is already in in the query: `"a": {$ne: 1}` and only then, make the update.

Comment: @Raz that's 2 operations over the wire. the bulkwrite command is a single operation over the wire.

Comment: @Raz updated my answer with a single push operation. but with that you can't replace the matching array object. it will only add if it doesn't exist. so if you supply a newer object with a newer timestamp, it will be discarded.